# struts2 jquery subgrid change height row

Tags: struts2, height, jqgrid

I'm using jQueryGrid with Struts2.
When I work with a subgrid row height is changed.
Is it possible to set the row height?
thanks

Comment: its always best to ask your question with some code snap shot as it always help others to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `subgrid` [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid_as_grid). That will help you understand the options to use. Hope this helps.